# kubeflow jupyter notebook error-Could not find CSRF cookie XSRF-TOKEN in the request

Tags: kubernetes, https, csrf-token, kubeflow

I installed kubeflow v1.4.0 on ubuntu 20.04 with the following specifications:

- k v1.21.7
- kustomize v3.1.0

however when i try to create a new notebook, i encounter the following error:
`Could not find CSRF cookie XSRF-TOKEN in the request`

i found a solution that adding the following lines

```
- name: APP_SECURE_COOKIES
    value: "false"
```

to the spec.env section of the manifests/apps/jupyter/jupyter-web-app/upstream/base/deployment.yaml would be helpful, but when i tried to build the yaml with this command

`kustomize build apps/jupyter/jupyter-web-app/upstream/overlays/istio | kubectl apply -f -`

i got this error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [12] with length 12 [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: index out of range [12] with length 12

goroutine 1 [running]:
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.handleErr(0xc000ca38f0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/yaml.go:276 +0x85
panic(0xbedf00, 0xc001c03140)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x1b9
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.write(0xc000683500, 0xc002c6e0c0, 0xc, 0x10, 0xc000c9ed90, 0x829c01)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/emitterc.go:90 +0x245
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.yaml_emitter_write_comment(0xc000683500, 0xc002c6e0c0, 0xc, 0x10, 0x1)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/emitterc.go:1978 +0x1ae
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.yaml_emitter_process_line_comment(0xc000683500, 0xc000cab5f0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/emitterc.go:1128 +0x6a
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.yaml_emitter_emit_block_mapping_value(0xc000683500, 0xc000cab5f0, 0x418801, 0x1)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/emitterc.go:817 +0xec
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.yaml_emitter_state_machine(0xc000683500, 0xc000cab5f0, 0x127d201)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/emitterc.go:303 +0x445
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.yaml_emitter_emit(0xc000683500, 0xc000683740, 0xc002c6e0d0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/emitterc.go:153 +0x14f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).emit(0xc000683500)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:81 +0x39
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).emitScalar(0xc000683500, 0xc001e377a0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc001990f02, 0x1285808, 0x0, ...)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:417 +0x31a
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0030d19a0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:559 +0x136f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0030d17c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:508 +0xb25
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0030d0aa0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:478 +0x5fc
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0002f5c20, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:512 +0xa6f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0002f5ae0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:478 +0x5fc
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0002f5860, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:512 +0xa6f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0001c7220, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:512 +0xa6f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0006adf40, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:512 +0xa6f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0006ad900, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:512 +0xa6f
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).node(0xc000683500, 0xc0006ad7c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:463 +0x245
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).nodev(0xc000683500, 0xbb3a00, 0xc0006ad7c0, 0x16)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:421 +0x79
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*encoder).marshalDoc(0xc000683500, 0x0, 0x0, 0xbb3a00, 0xc0006ad7c0, 0x16)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/encode.go:101 +0x23a
gopkg.in/yaml%2ev3.(*Encoder).Encode(0xc00000e7f8, 0xbb3a00, 0xc0006ad7c0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200313102051-9f266ea9e77c/yaml.go:251 +0xea
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml/yaml.String(0xc0006ad7c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml@v0.10.9/yaml/types.go:215 +0x1b3
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml/yaml.(*RNode).String(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml@v0.10.9/yaml/rnode.go:468
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml/yaml.(*RNode).MarshalJSON(0xc002f26b40, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc001990230)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kyaml@v0.10.9/yaml/rnode.go:674 +0x37a
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api/internal/wrappy.(*WNode).MarshalJSON(0xc000102828, 0x17c, 0x180, 0x502ab9, 0xc000ba8067, 0xc000346600)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api@v0.8.0/internal/wrappy/wnode.go:219 +0x2e
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api/resource.(*Resource).MarshalJSON(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api@v0.8.0/resource/resource.go:106
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api/resource.(*Resource).AsYAML(0xc000076f00, 0xc000346600, 0x174, 0x200, 0x174, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api@v0.8.0/resource/resource.go:359 +0x38
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api/resmap.(*resWrangler).AsYaml(0xc0003916a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/api@v0.8.0/resmap/reswrangler.go:273 +0x10c
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3/commands/build.(*Options).emitResources(0xc0004307e0, 0xd2f000, 0xc000102008, 0xd4eac0, 0x1285808, 0xd52560, 0xc0003916a0, 0xc0002d5880, 0xc0000bdd98)
        /workspace/myClone/kustomize/commands/build/build.go:160 +0x4e
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3/commands/build.(*Options).RunBuild(0xc0004307e0, 0xd2f000, 0xc000102008, 0x1, 0x0)
        /workspace/myClone/kustomize/commands/build/build.go:152 +0x135
sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3/commands/build.NewCmdBuild.func1(0xc000450000, 0xc0003b8ee0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /workspace/myClone/kustomize/commands/build/build.go:70 +0xad
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc000450000, 0xc0003b8eb0, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc000450000, 0xc0003b8eb0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:842 +0x47c
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc00015f8c0, 0x0, 0xb3aa40, 0xc000078058)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:950 +0x375
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.0.0/command.go:887
main.main()
        /workspace/myClone/kustomize/main.go:14 +0x2a
error: no objects passed to apply
```

I also tried another command:

`kubectl apply -f apps/jupyter/jupyter-web-app/upstream/base/deployment.yaml`

but this time i got this error

```
error: error validating "apps/jupyter/jupyter-web-app/upstream/base/deployment.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Anyone if you know the cause and solution, I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Check out these discussions https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/5803#issuecomment-817310731, https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/5803#issuecomment-817318286, https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/5803#issuecomment-817327707

Comment: under this issue https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/5803